# activity onBackPressed() causing GC which delay activity response

Tags: android, garbage-collection, android-activity

I'm facing an issue which when i move from activity B back to activity A (via back pressed) causing a lot of GC (show in logcat) which make the app stop like ~1 second before back to activity A.

any one got any solution for this ?

kiwi

Comment: Perhaps ActivityB is creating way too many objects that need to be cleaned up when you leave it. Perhaps you should look at reducing the number of objects that ActivityB is creating.

Comment: after some debug, I found that is the my code render double result due to wrongly use of fragment, now I dun have this issue anymore, thx !

Answer (score 0):

GC shouldn't take that long, changing an activity in Android is not a quick task, needing to cycle through the pausing callbacks of the ending activity and the resuming callbacks of the returned activity.
This is probably what takes up the most time, so I would start by measuring how much time is spent on these callbacks: `onPause`, `onStop`, `onDestroy`, `onStart`, `onResume` of both activities.

You can also use the Android tool [TraceView](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/traceview.html) to profile your activities and see what takes too long.

**It is not recommended**, but if you insist on trying to prevent the GC, you can manually call it before the user hits the back key, so the memory will be as free as possible, and you'll have less chance of getting hit by hit when the activities change, for that you can call `System.gc()`

Comment: after some debug, I found that is the my code render double result due to wrongly use of fragment, now I dun have this issue anymore, thx !